# Do you attach index data to VAO (Vertex Array Objects)?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl2

I understand that with VAOs, it's ideal to provide all attributes data, such as vertex normals, vertex positions, vertex colors, texture coordinates, etc. but what about index data in situations for drawing with `drawElements` rather than `drawArrays`?

So far, I create a VAO and provide the data above but not sure how to attach index buffer data to the VAO (if that's even recommended or possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No data of any buffer is stored in the vertex array object. The vertex array object just collects information how to "use" the data of different buffers.
It knows things like data format, type, stride offset and the names of the buffers, but it doesn't "mirror" the data which is stored in the buffer objects.

The name of the named element buffer object is a state of the vertex array objects state vector.

This means there are no data stored in the Vertex Array Object. The indices are stored in the element buffer, but the name (integral object number) of the index buffer is referenced in the vertex array object.

The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` has to be bound after the vertex array object has been bound (`glBindVertexArray`). The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` object is stored in the vertex array objects state vector.
If the vertex array object has been unbound and is bound again, then the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is known and bound again too. But if the element array buffer explicitly gets unbound while the vertex array object is bound, it is removed form the state vector.

See the [OpenGL ES 3.0.5 Specification - 2.11 Vertex Array Objects, page 44](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> A vertex array object is created by binding a name returned by `GenVertexArrays`
>   with the command
>
> ```
> void BindVertexArray( uint array );
> ```
>
> array is the vertex array object name. The resulting vertex array object is a new state vector, comprising all the state and with the same initial values listed in table 6.2.
>   `BindVertexArray` may also be used to bind an existing vertex array object.
>   If the bind is successful no change is made to the state of the bound vertex array object, and any previous binding is broken.
>
> Tables 6.2, Vertex Array Object State
>   `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ENABLED`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_STRIDE`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_TYPE`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_NORMALIZED`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_INTEGER`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_DIVISOR`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_POINTER`, **`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`**, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`.

---

> I'm curious whether index buffer object data or uniforms would be somehow stored inside of VAOs? 
>   Uniforms are stored to the default uniform block which belongs to the program object.

Uniforms are stored to the default uniform block which belongs to the program object, there is no relation to the vertex array object.

Comment: Yes, I understand the binding and unbinding of these attributes. I'm curious whether index buffer object data or uniforms would be somehow stored inside of VAOs? I ask, because it seems like VAOs encapsulate functionality for a particular entity. Given that IBO (index buffer objects) also encapsulate that for a single entity, why not have that somehow contained inside of the VAO? Is that possible? If so, how do you do it? Thank you!

Comment: @Detuned I extended the answer.

Comment: So it sounds like VAOs are simply instructions and not data. If that's the case, then indices data doesn't go there, because there are no "instructions" in pulling data out. It's simply a bind and draw call with drawElement. Is that correct?

Comment: @Detuned Yes, Vertex array objects consists of tables. In this tables are contained the references to the buffer objects and the information which buffer to use for which attribute. The index buffer is a single reference.  There is not any index or attribute value in the VAO.